# Delete from one, add to another Listbox and vice versa with the same sorting like before

Tags: c#

I have to small events to delete the selected items from one list and add them to another and vice versa and it works fine.
The Problem is that when i delete the items from the second list and add them again to the first list that the sorting is add the end of the list.
Is it possible to save the "position" to add them on the same place like before?

Solutions like list.sort() wouldn't work because its a database with all tables and triggers and so on...

```
        private void LstSelectedDbTables_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstSelectedDbTables.SelectedIndex != -1)
            if (e.KeyValue == (char) Keys.Delete || e.KeyValue == (char) Keys.Back)
            {
                var selectedItems = lstSelectedDbTables.SelectedItems;
                var bdHashSet = new List<string>(lstSourceDatabaseTables.Items.Cast<string>());
                for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    bdHashSet.Add(selectedItems[i].ToString());
                    lstSelectedDbTables.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
                }
                lstSourceDatabaseTables.DataSource = bdHashSet;
            }
    }

    private void lstSourceDatabaseTables_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstSourceDatabaseTables.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var bdHashSet = new HashSet<string>(lstSourceDatabaseTables.Items.Cast<string>());
            var selectedItems = lstSourceDatabaseTables.SelectedItems;

            for (int i = selectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                lstSelectedDbTables.Items.Add(selectedItems[i]);
                bdHashSet.Remove(selectedItems[i].ToString());
            }
            lstSourceDatabaseTables.DataSource = bdHashSet.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add items to `List<T>` to specific place in your list, beacuse `List<T>.Add()`

> Adds an object to the end of the List.

You could create simple List not attached to database context in any way, do your operations like inserting and deleting and then pass list which is correctly ordered to save in your database. Then you could use `Sort` or `OrderBy` since these methods are designed to perform exactly, what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

you must made a list of array when the first column is "last index position" and the other column is "itemvalue"...so every time that you move an item from a list box to other you must copy in another list called temp of the same type all the elements of destination listbox from index n+1 until the end and delete each one after copied. Then insert the new element that you want move and insert all the item of temp list.